# creating social network relationship table

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi guys I need help in creating my relationship table. Basically it needs to look like this

[image]

user_one_id and user_two_id is foreign key from the user table, status show the current relationship status (0 for pending, 1 for friends, 2 for declined, 3 for blocked) and action_user_id is the id of the user who has make the most recent update on the status field. To avoid duplicate, I have add a unique on user_one_id and user_two_id. Now I want user_one_id to **always be smaller than** user_two_id. This is where I am stuck. Here is what I have come up with so far

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS relationship (
user_one_id NOT NULL,
user_two_id NOT NULL,
status ENUM ('0','1','2','3') NOT NULL,
action_user_id NOT NULL,
UNIQUE (user_one_id, user_two_id))
```

Comment: Why does user 1 ID always need to be less than user 2 id?

Comment: I you want to achieve this you could simply make a condition on the insert statement.

Comment: @PeterM could you show me?

Comment: @axlj I am under assumption it would make query easier, no?

Comment: @tien318 I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a constraint to the table (assuming the foreign keys are integers?)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS relationship (
    user_one_id INT NOT NULL,
    user_two_id INT NOT NULL,
    status ENUM ('0','1','2','3') NOT NULL,
    action_user_id NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (user_one_id, user_two_id)
    CONSTRAINT CHK_users CHECK (user_one_id < user_two_id)
)
```

This will guarantee that only unique pairs of ids are stored.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you an example to achieve this on `INSERT` level.

```
SET @id_one = 10;
SET @id_two = 20;
INSERT INTO relationship (user_one_id, user_two_id, status, action_user_id) VALUES (
    (CASE 
        WHEN @id_one >= @id_two THEN @id_two
        ELSE  @id_one
    END),
    (CASE 
        WHEN @id_one >= @id_two THEN @id_one
        ELSE  @id_two
    END),
    0,  <--- you need to set this one yourself
    10  <--- you need to set this one yourself
);
```